# D mixins with string switch statements

Tags: d, mixins

I have a D mixin that I'd like to use to generate a switch statement (case values, specifically) on string values, but despite `KeyValues` having entries in it and providing the right key values, the default case is always the only one executed:

```
class DataStore(KeyValues...) {
    void stringSetData(string key, string data) {
        switch(key) {
            foreach(D; KeyValues) {
                mixin("case \"" ~ D.Name ~ "\": set(to!(D.Type)(data)); break;");
            }
            default:
                throw new Exception("Invalid meta key"); break;
        }
    }
}
```

I've tested this with hard-coded values, and it works as expected, so my suspicion is that I might be doing something wrong with my mixin itself. How can I get this to work as expected?

Comment: Are you even allowed to have a `foreach` inside a `switch` like that? I've never seen that before...

Comment: Mehrdad: it's a `foreach` over a tuple, so it's unrolled at compile-time (see "Foreach over Tuples" [here](http://www.d-programming-language.org/statement.html#ForeachStatement)).

Comment: Mark: I assume `KeyValues` / `KeyValue` is a typo?

Comment: @CyberShadow: Yes, I'll correct that now. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Not a direct solution to your problem, but is there a reason you don't mixin the whole switch statement? I think this'd be cleaner:

Comment: Sorry, forget about that, I think the code will only get uglier with that suggestion.

Comment: Last time I checked, that example code has no need for a string mixin; the value of a case label can be a const value from a foreach: http://dsource.org/projects/scrapple/browser/trunk/dparser/dparse.d#L148

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `break` inside the mixin is breaking from the `foreach` loop, not the `switch`. Replace it with `return`, or a labelled `break`.

By the way, if you try to compile this code with warnings enabled, you get some weird error messages from DMD.